# How can i get device, manufacturer and model in a device that support J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, operating-system, nokia, system-properties

I have a nokia 2730 and want to read model and manufacturer, how can i do it using a j2me application?

Could someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `microedition.platform` system property. It usually includes device information. You can see its format on [Nokia documentation](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!developers-guides/application-framework/system-properties/generic-system-properties.html)